# Remove trailing spaces after value in database

Tags: sql, database

I am playing around with some values in a database and I have noticed that if I declare the column value type nvarchar(100) and put in the value "hello" the value becomes "Hello       " with spaces to make it a 100 characters. Is there a way to remove this? Thanks beforehand! I am trying to use the values in a ASP.NET Core 3 MVC application.

Best regards,
Max

Comment: I'd say this is an interface issue.

Comment: If this is Microsoft SQL Server, you probably had [the `ANSI_PADDING` setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-padding-transact-sql) turned on when the columns were added. If they're really `nvarchar` and not `nchar`, then you must be inserting the values with the trailing spaces.

Comment: @RichardDeeming Can I remove the "padding"? Do you want me to post the column properties?

Comment: For MS SQL Server, and assuming it's definitely an `nvarchar` and not an `nchar`, you could update the column using the `RTrim` function: `UPDATE t SET c = RTrim(c)`.

Comment: Well, I ran this query and nothing happened UPDATE dbo.Images SET Filepath = RTrim(Filepath)

Comment: Should the columns be nchar instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, allow the column to be null!